# Django ошибка AttributeError at /login/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, аутентификация

Я делаю авторизацию на сайте django, используя этот гайд: https://proproprogs.ru/django/delaem-avtorizaciyu-polzovateley-na-sayte.

Я создал views.py

```
class LoginUser(DataMixin, LoginView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'shop/login.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Авторизация")
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))
```

потом в urls.py добавил path login

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('add_product', add_product, name='add_product'),
    path('login/', LoginUser.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

но при переходе на сайт через http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ у меня появляется ошибка:

> AttributeError at /login/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Answer (score 0):

Я же не создал DataMixin и импортировал его вообще из другой библиотеки Aiogram. Надо было по порядку гайды смотреть